How do you fix an IntelliJ module that shows up blank?
I keep having this happen where sometimes when I add a new package to my project it shows up as just blank when I look at the module settings, like so:

The white rectangles are me obfuscating my project info, but you can see that the entire area where the module settings would be is just blank grey.
IntelliJ recently crashed on me, and when I reopened it, half of the modules in my project looked like this.  It's extremely frustrating and I have no idea how to fix it since there aren't any configuration options for me to toggle on the module since the whole thing is showing as blank.
Does anyone know why this happens?  Is there some trick to workaround this?

If it's a maven/gradle project, try reimporting the project by clicking on the "refresh icon" in the corresponding tool window. Otherwise (or if this fails) nuke it with File -> Invalidate caches, restart, reopen projects and have a coffee while it rebuilds the whole thing.
